# Naming convention for this group of functionalities

Tags: naming-conventions

I have Login form,forget password form and register form in a single page.. What can be the name given to the webpage? Any suggestion..

Comment: What do you mean by sign in form and register form? How do they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it the "Log in" or "Sign in" page (they mean the same thing), as that is the ultimate goal of the page. Registration is just an extra step some people will have to take to be able to log in.